# Me fallan los enlaces permanentes en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

he cambiado los enlaces permanentes en ajustes. he creado el .htaccess con el código que me ha dado wordpress, también he habilitado el mod rewrite en apache y le he dado permisos 777 al .htaccess pero aun me fallan los enlaces.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /adela/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /adela/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirígete a tu BDD, tabla "wp_options" y modifica el campo "permalink_structure"

Si lo usabas por defecto, llénalo con: /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Comment: gracias maguz... llevaba un buen rato dandole vueltas